# Why is this simple :after and :before pseudo element not working?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Why is the pseudo class not working?

Here is the fiddle with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Midtone/DCDVM/

It seems simple enough but I can not get it to work in any browser.  Is this a Coda bug?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems that you're trying to absolutely position the elements with `left: 0; right: 0;` then you'll need to add.

```
position: absolute;
```

Then you can start to see what you're playing with... Beyond that... I can't really decipher what you're trying to do aside from display the css you're working with.

## http://jsfiddle.net/DCDVM/2/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any dimensions (in that context) for those pseudo-elements. That's why they don't appear.

`top` and `left` are ignored for elements with `position: static` (the default).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCDVM/5/).